Wanting to disable a button in .net Maui when entry is not a number
I am trying to have two entry that are numbers if they are numbers enable the button. If not enable the button. I created a sample app to test this.
What i tried so far created a class that checks if it is a double and changes the text to green if double or red if not. That works. I tried muititrgger conditions in the button. My thought was to check if the entry text color was red or green to control the button. I am placing my code below.
public class NumericValidationTriggerAction : TriggerAction<Entry>
{
    
    protected override void Invoke (Entry entry)
    {
        double result;
        bool isValid = Double.TryParse(entry.Text, out result);
        entry.TextColor = isValid ? Colors.Black : Colors.Red;
       
    }
}

<StackLayout>
    <Label FontSize="20"
           Text="EventTrigger Example"/>

    <Label Text="Text must be a valid double or it will turn red"/>
    <Entry x:Name="email" 
        Placeholder="Enter a System.Double"
           >
        <Entry.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger Event="TextChanged">
                <local:NumericValidationTriggerAction/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Entry.Triggers>
    </Entry>

    <Button
        Text="Save"
        IsEnabled="False">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger TargetType="Button">
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference email}, Path=Double.TryParse.email}" Value="Green"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</StackLayout>


Wouldn't it make more sense to use a converter/behavior instead, it will be way more hassle proof.

You are not using [Model-View-ViewModel] that's why it's complicated.
Think about this :
<Entry x:Name="email" TextChanged="email_TextChanged" Placeholder="Enter a System.Double" />

In the code behind you can access other controls :
private void email_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Your Actions here
    double result;
    bool isValid = Double.TryParse(email.Text, out result);
    email.TextColor = isValid ? Colors.Black : Colors.Red;

    //Set name to your button in Xaml to access it here
    MyButton.IsEnabled = isValid;
}

<StackLayout>
    <Label FontSize="20"
           Text="EventTrigger Example"/>

    <Label Text="Text must be a valid double or it will turn red"/>

    <Entry x:Name="email"
           TextChanged="email_TextChanged" 
           Placeholder="Enter a System.Double">
    </Entry>

    <Button
        x:Name="MyButton"
        Text="Save"
        IsEnabled="False">
    </Button>
</StackLayout>


Update: using [Model-View-ViewModel]
Confirm you have installed those packages from [NuGet Package Manager] (stable versions)
 - CommunityToolkit.Maui
 - CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core
 - CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

Create a new ContentView [MyContentView] & new Class [MyViewModel_1]
Just copy paste the code to test it

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.MyViewModelsFolder"
             x:DataType="ViewModels:MyViewModel_1"
             x:Class="MyNameSpace.MyViewsFolder.MyContentView">
    
    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:MyViewModel_1 x:Name="MyViewModel_1"/>
    </ContentView.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label FontSize="20" Text="Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) Example"/>

        <Label Text="Text must be a valid double or it will turn red"/>

        <Entry Text="{Binding Email}" TextColor="{Binding Email_TextColor}" Placeholder="Enter a System.Double"/>

        <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding MyButtonClickedActionCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding MyButton_IsEnabled}"/>
    </StackLayout>
    
</ContentView>


using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace MyNameSpace.MyViewModelsFolder
{
    public partial class MyViewModel_1 : ObservableObject
    {
       
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _Email = string.Empty;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private Color _Email_TextColor = Colors.Black; 
        
        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _MyButton_IsEnabled = false; 

        partial void OnEmailChanged(string? oldValue, string newValue)
        {
            //Your Actions here
            double result;
            bool isValid = Double.TryParse(newValue, out result);
            Email_TextColor = isValid ? Colors.Black : Colors.Red;

            MyButton_IsEnabled = isValid;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void MyButtonClickedAction()
        {
           
        }
    }
}


this is NOT MVVM

Yes, I know that, it's not right to force him to use mvvm unless he requested that. I'm trying to answer as close as possible to the question code base.

I want to check on how to switch it to mvvm. I have 2 entrys, 4 labels and two buttons. In the viewmodel file I would need to do for the labels and entry the following
Private double price;
Public string Price
{
Get = > price;
Set
{
get => price
OnProperty Changed();
}
Then in setting up in the mainpage.xaml.cs
Private mainViewmodel vm = new MainViewModel();
Then under mainpage
Binding context = vm
entry/label to text={“Binding Price”}
Main questions how would I check the entrys and display the button like in the other example. I know spelling and punctuation may be wrong.

I will switch my answer to MVVM, so you will get the general idea of MVVM , but you have to learn more about it.
